# When switching on enum, why does the code not work when I put round brackets () around the switch case but works otherwise?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have an enum, States, on which I am trying to do a switch statement on. I understand that it needs the unqualified name of enum constant, so I put `ZERO_Init` instead of `States.ZERO_Init` in the switch case. The code below works fine when ZERO_Init is not surrounded by () brackets, but complains about "Constant expression needed" if I put () around ZERO_Init. Why is this the case?

Below please find my code.

```
enum States{
   ZERO_Init,
   ...
}

//current_state of type States is defined elsewhere
```

This version works,

```
switch (current_state){
   case ZERO_Init:{
      //do something
      break;
   }
   default:{
      //do something else
      break;
   }
}
```

Whereas this does not,

```
switch (current_state){
   case (ZERO_Init):{ //ERROR: CONSTANT EXPRESSION NEEDED
      //do something
      break;
   }
   default:{
      //do something else
      break;
   }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Most compiled languages will give you a compilation error if you write code that doesn't conform to the syntax rules of the language.  Java is no exception.

Comment: It's worth noting that those brackets are superfluous noise, so even if this were allowed, I'd consider it a fault of style anyway.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the question is why Java's syntax rules don't consider `(ZERO_Init)` to be a "constant expression".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just learned that "constant expression" does not constitute the full set of things that are compile-time constant, which is perhaps unintuitive. `(ZERO_Init)` is compile-time constant, just like `ZERO_Init` is. Take for example [the spec for annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1). Everything in an annotation must be compile-time constant by definition. There is no possibility for them to be computed at runtime. Still, the spec has 3 bullet points listing what's valid, and so-called "constant expressions" are only one of them.

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6356542

Comment: I get that, @KarlKnechtel, but that's really a question for the designers of Java - those good people who formulated these rules.  I'm not sure whether the Stack Overflow community as a whole is qualified to answer WHY the rules of Java syntax are what they are.

Comment: I now understand that I seem to have asked a question that questions Java's syntax rules' design. Me in the past was confused of whether brackets meant something more when it comes to enum. I am more than happy to accept the answer that it is simply a design choice for the syntax, and it is how it is specified (rather than asking for further explanation why it is designed as it is).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply because Java is specified this way. If you're switching on an `enum` then every case label must be exactly a enum constant (and not a parenthetical expression *containing* a case constant): [§ 14.11.1 Switch blocks of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.1) states:

> If T is an enum type, then every case constant associated with the switch block is an enum constant of type T.

Note that technically only expressions that denote a primitive or `String` value could be considered constant expressions. See [§ 15.29 Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` [..]

Comment: I think that error as stated is an IntelliJ error, and I agree it's bad. `javac` gives you "an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant", which is pretty descriptive.

Comment: @Michael I was using Android Studio, yes. Though it did give me a more descriptive error when I had `States.ZERO_Init` in.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a rule of thumb when it comes to identifying when `()` brackets matter (more than just poor coding style)? For example, is there a way to tell that `if ((//condition))` is allowed whereas the mentioned case is not? Or is it entirely a matter of reading the specs and experience?

Comment: the rule of thumb is that "unnecessary" parenthesis are allowed almost everywhere where you want the value of an expression (i.e. the expression `(x)` is functionally identical to `x` in almost all contexts). Case labels for enums are only excluded because they are not "expressions". A case label can be specifically a.) a constant expression or b.) an enum constant.